# Inheritance and static type java

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

I was playing around with classes since I'm learning java syntax and I came across this weird situation. So given a class `A` and `B`:

```
public class A {
     public int x() {
         return x;
     }
}

public class B extends A {
    int x = 5;
    public int x() {
        return x + 2;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        System.out.println(b.x());
}
```

When I execute the main method I get a compile time error that it doesn't find the `x` variable and it's calling the method from `A` because the error shows `return x` instead of `return x + 2`. Since `b`'s static type is `B`, why is it looking in `A` for `x`?

```
error: cannot find symbol

return x;

symbol: variable x
location: class A
```

Comment: Class `A` doesn´t have a variable called `x`,that you are trying to return in your function `A#x`.

Comment: You don't have any declarations of `int x` in your class A.

Comment: `return x;` ==> `x` is defined in `B`, `A` has no way of knowing it

Comment: In short - `A` doesn't refer to `B` anywhere - so should be able to compile without it even existing. So imagine you'd removed `B.java` - would you expect `A.java` to be able to compile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class `A` doesn't *know* that it will be extended by `B`, where the `x` variable will exist.

In order to make this compile, make `A.x()` abstract and provide implementation within the subclass:

```
public abstract class A {
     public abstract int x();
}

public class B extends A {
    int x = 5;

    @Override
    public int x() {
        return x + 2;
    }
..
}
```

Comment: Great, I understand now I was too focused on the declaration of the new object and thinking that had something to do with it. Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating the Object of class B, it automatically invoke the x() of class A, But x is not initialized in that class. As it is a local variable, it can not be used without initialization. so it is giving an error.

Try the below code, it is working correctly

```
class A 
{
    int x =10;
    public int x() 
    {
        return x;
    }
}
class B extends A
{
    int x = 5;
    public int x() 
    {
        return x + 2;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        B b = new B();
        System.out.println(b.x());
    }
}
```